# What should be length of keyword using for meta keyword tag?

Tags: keywords, meta-tags, meta-keywords

I want to know that what is character count limit to use Meta Keyword as per Search Engine Optimization policy

like Title should not be extend than 70 Characters or Meta Description must less than 155 characters

Answer (score 2):

[Search engines do not use the meta keywords tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) in ranking, since it is so easily abused, so any "character limit" is irrelevant.

You can use it for your own internal use if required, but otherwise it's unnecessary.

Comment: I was thinking that some search engines not considers keywords, is that all search engines like yahoo, being and other not considers keywords to optimization?

Comment: For a long time now _all_ major search engines do not use the meta keywords tag as a ranking factor. However, there might still be some niche search engines (or tools) that do still use this tag - but this would be very much an edge case and particular to the tool and your site.